# How can I evaluate the result of an adb shell command?

Tags: bash, shell, command-substitution, adb

For example, I want to check if a directory exists on the phone.

```
R=$(adb shell 'ls /mnt/; echo $?' | tail -1);

$ echo $R
0

$ if [ "$R" -ne 0 ]; then echo "Path doesn't exist"; else echo "Path exists"; fi
: integer expression expected
Path exists
```

What's wrong with R? Ok, try it with another variable which is definitely 0.

```
$ x=0
$ if [ "$x" -ne 0 ]; then echo "Path doesn't exist"; else echo "Path exists"; fi

Path exists

$ echo "|$x|"
|0|

$ echo "|$R|"
|0
```

The second pipe isn't printed. Is there a character after 0? Try to trim:

```
$ R=$(adb shell 'ls /mnt/; echo $?' | tail -1 | xargs)
$ echo "|$R|"
|0
```

I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`adb` is adding a carriage-return (aka `0x0d`, `Ctrl-M`, `\r`, etc) before the line-feed.  Probably for ease of use with Windows software that expects lines to end with CR-LF rather than just LF.

You can see this yourself with `hexdump` aka `hd`, e.g.:

```
$ printf "$R" | hd
00000000  30 0d                                             |0.|
00000002
```

Because you only need to return a single value (the exit code). you could use `printf` instead of `echo` and redirect all of `ls`'s output to `/dev/null` on the Android device to avoid printing any newlines (then adb doesn't add a CR):

```
R="$(adb shell 'ls /mnt/ > /dev/null 2>&1 ; printf $?')"
```

If your android device doesn't have `printf`, or if you need to return one or more lines of output from a the android shell, you can use `tr -d '\r'` or `dos2unix` or `sed 's/\r$//'` or similar to strip the CR.

`dos2unix` and `sed` are better choices than `tr` here because they will only strip CRs that are immediately followed by LF, leaving alone any CRs that might be in elsewhere in a line:

```
$ R="$(adb shell 'ls /mnt/ > /dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?' | dos2unix)"
$ printf "$R" | hd
00000000  30                                                |0|
00000001
```

Comment: 'printf not found'

Comment: what kind of android device is that?   `printf` is even on my ancient HTC Desire HD which I just tested this with (running CM7, not original HTC Android).   I'll update with solution for android without printf.

Comment: btw, `hexdump` aka `hd` is a good tool for diagnosing all sorts of weird 'huh, WTF?'  problems like this.   It makes it easy to see exactly what input or output you are getting (with hex bytes and ascii representation in `hd`'s default output format)

Comment: Acer Liquid E2 Duo. Bought 2013 or 2014.
Your solution with use of 'tr' works.

Comment: my HTC phone is from 2010.  but its running CyanogenMod 7, not stock HTC android.  Doesn't matter, `tr` will work whether the device has `printf` or not.

Comment: Please use 2> so that there is still one line in case of an error (path doesn't exist). Or it may be still better to use 'tail -1'.

Comment: The culprit is adb, not echo. Adb adds CR, which is very annoying, for example, when you want to do something like `adb shell tar -cf - …`.

Comment: I hate android™. So many bad design decisions. So many hours wasted.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer does a good job explaining where the asker went wrong. 
 The moral of the story is to be wary of counting characters, since adb might add some.

I wound up doing this

```
R=$(adb shell 'ls /mnt && echo SUCCESS || echo FAIL' | egrep (SUCCESS|FAIL))
echo $R
```